# How to add a # before any line containing a matching pattern in BASH?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I need to add a `#` before any line containing the pattern "000", e.g., consider this sample file:

```
This is a 000 line.
This is 000 yet ano000ther line.
This is still yet another line.
```

If I run the command, it should add `#` to the front of any files where "000" was found. The result would be this:

```
#This is a 000 line.
#This is 000 yet ano000ther line.
This is still yet another line.
```

The best I can do is a while loop, like this, which seems too complicated:

```
while read -r line
do
    if [[ $line == *000* ]]
    then
          echo "#"$line >> output.txt
    else
          echo $line >> output.txt
    fi
done < file.txt
```

How can I add a `#` to the front of any line where a pattern is found?

Comment: You can use the sed command to accomplish this, but have you consider doing this with a text editor? In vim for example this task can be easily automated through macros.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*000/#&/' file
```

Comment: Village thanks,but I think Tim Cooper's answer is probably a better solution using sed. When using sed it is usually accepted that a search followed by a substitution is more efficient than a sole substitution command (however I think single quoting a sed command on the commandline, is generally safer especially when that command may be ameliorated at some future date).

Comment: If I want to add # after 9 lines and below 2 lines of matching pattern. I tried below two sed commnads but not working can you please help.                                                                    sed /create_rev -name "FLK"/-2,+9s/^/# and
sed '/create_rev -name "ALK"/-2,+9s/^/#'

Comment: @Rama why not ask for a solution in the form of a new question?

Comment: sure I will ask a new question.

Answer (score 73):

The following sed command will work for you, which does not require any capture groups:

```
sed /000/s/^/#/
```

Explanation:

- `/000/` matches a line with `000`
- `s` perform a substitution on the lines matched above
- The substitution will insert a pound character (`#`) at the beginning of the line (`^`)

Comment: This does not need any quotes around it? I never see a `sed` script without those.

Comment: @Village:  Since there are no special characters that bash will try to interpret (the `#` doesn't cause any issues because it is part of a larger word), the quotes are not necessary.

Comment: @TimCooper Thanks for the help, I needed something for MYSQL config file and this worked for me `sed -i '/bind-address/s/^/#/' /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Comment: @TimCooper, If I want to add # after 9 lines and below 2 lines of matching pattern. I tried below code but not working can you please help.                                                                    sed /create_rev -name "FLK"/-2,+9s/^/#  and 
sed '/create_rev -name "ALK"/-2,+9s/^/#'

Answer (score 4):

the question was how to add the poundsign to those lines in a file so to make tim coopers excellent answer more complete i would suggest the following:

```
sed /000/s/^/#/ > output.txt
```

or you could consider using sed's ability to in-place edit the file in question and also make a backup copy like:

```
sed -i.bak /000/s/^/#/ file.txt
```

the "-i" option will edit and save the file inline/in-place 
the "-i.bak" option will also backup the original file to file.txt.bak in case you screw up something.

you can replace ".bak" with any suffix to your liking.
eg: "-i.orignal" will create the original file as: "file.txt.orignal"

Answer (score 1):

or use `ed`:

```
echo -e "g/000/ s/^/#/\nw\nq" | ed -s FILENAME
```

or open file in ed :

```
ed FILENAME
```

and write this command

```
g/000/ s/^/#/
w
q
```

Comment: Well, yeah, it works, but to me it seems pointless to manually type in, or pipe stuff to, an interactive program like `ed` - when there exist dedicated non-interactive tools for doing this, like `sed`. Also, for example, `sed` was installed by default on my Debian system, but `ed` isn't. And the `sed` version has much less bloat in the command string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this GNU sed command,

```
$ sed -r '/000/ s/^(.*)$/#\1/g' file
#This is a 000 line.
#This is 000 yet ano000ther line.
This is still yet another line.
```

**Explanation:**

- `/000/` sed substitution only works on the line which contans `000`. Once it finds the corresponding line, it adds `#` symbol infront of it.

And through awk,

```
$ awk '/000/{gsub (/^/,"#")}1' file
#This is a 000 line.
#This is 000 yet ano000ther line.
This is still yet another line
```

- `gsub` function is used to add `#` infront of the lines which contains `000`.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but there's no reason to capture `(.*)` just to replace it with itself `\1` -- `s/^/#/` is much simpler